# QT Creator doesn't start on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

I am new to QT, and familiar with Linux/Ubuntu.

I installed:

1. sudo apt-get install build-essential
2. sudo apt-get install qtcreator
3. sudo apt-get install qt4-default
4. sudo apt-get install qt4doc
5. sudo apt-get install qt4doc-html qtbase5-doc-html
6. sudo apt-get install qtbase4examples

But when I do `Applications > Programming > Qt Creator`
it displays a Qt icon in the lower screen tray, it this disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: Try running it from terminal to at least see some output.

Comment: Have you been able to run QT Creator from the terminal? This won't fix the problem, but you should be able to at least see any log output or errors the application is producing before it fails.

Comment: Qt4 is really old, are you sure it's even possible to run it on a modern Linux setup?